# What is the antipattern involved in the below code

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, inheritance, autowired

I have the following code,

```
public abstract class ClassA {

    public String execute() {
        System.out.println("Do something...");
        return processData();
    }
    
    protected abstract String processData();

    protected String callMethodFromAbstractClass(String somedata) {
        return somedata;
    }
    
}

  public class ClassB extends ClassA {
        
        private String somedata;
        
        public ClassB (String somedata) {
            this.somedata= somedata;
        }
    
        @Override
        protected String processData() {
            return callMethodFromAbstractClass(somedata);
        }
        
    }
```

How we call this from caller class is like below

```
ClassA classA = ClassB("somedata");
classA.execute();
```

In the above code,

1. the child class method is called from the parent class method since the abstract method is defined in the parent class method - Is there any anti pattern / issue involved in this ?
2. If I need to autowire (`@autowired`) the ClassA and ClassB as Spring Beans, how do I achieve it

   ClassA classA = ClassB("somedata");
   classA.execute();

Comment: `protected String callMethodFromAbstractClass(String somedata)` but you call `callMethodFromAbstractClass();` - does this compile?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I masked the code for security and sorry I missed to add it, please let me know any antipattern involved in the code.

Answer (score 0):

1. 

I personally don't feel that it is an anti-pattern.  Your callMethodFromAbstractClass() method can be any helper method that extenders of ClassA want to reuse (or even override).  Imagine if instead it were normalizeDataFragment(String fragment).  Rather than have all of the classes having to know how to normalize a fragment, you have it in the abstract class, and then as the classes process the data, they can use it if/when they need to, or even override/extend it if desired.

2.

You don't Autowire classes, but rather instances of classes.  So, if you configure an instance of ClassB, and you want to autowire it into another class, you can use either ClassA or ClassB to autowire it:

```
@Autowired
private ClassA classA;

@Autowired
private ClassB classB;
```

Either will work, and will get a reference to your instance of ClassB, because from spring's perspective (and Java's), an instance of ClassB is both valid as an instance of ClassA and ClassB.

To create the instance itself, if using Java config, you would simply make a bean within your @Configuration class and instantiate it like you want.

```
@Bean
public ClassA classBWithSomeData() {
  return new ClassB("somedata");
}
```